# cbegin of the custom iterator does not get used

Tags: c++, c++11, const-iterator

I have defined two iterators over keys of a map:

```
template<class MyMap>
struct MapKeyIterator : MyMap::iterator {
    using Base = typename MyMap::iterator;
    using Key = typename MyMap::key_type;
    MapKeyIterator() : Base(){};
    MapKeyIterator(Base it_) : Base(it_){};

    Key *operator->() const { return &(Base::operator->()->first); }
    Key operator*() const { return Base::operator*().first; }
};

template<class MyMap>
struct MapKeyConstIterator : MyMap::const_iterator {
    using Base = typename MyMap::const_iterator;
    using Key = typename MyMap::key_type;
    MapKeyConstIterator() : Base(){};
    MapKeyConstIterator(Base it_) : Base(it_){};

    Key *operator->() const { return &(Base::operator->()->first); }
    Key operator*() const { return Base::operator*().first; }
};
```

The following type uses these iterators:

```
struct A {
    using MyMap = std::map<int, int>;
    using KeyIterator = MapKeyIterator<MyMap>;
    using KeyConstIterator = MapKeyConstIterator<MyMap>;

    KeyIterator begin() { return m.begin(); }
    KeyConstIterator cbegin() const { return m.cbegin(); }
    KeyIterator end() { return m.end(); }
    KeyConstIterator cend() const { return m.cend(); }
private:
    MyMap m{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}};
};
```

The following does not compile:

```
void f(const A &a) {
    for (const auto &el: a)
        std::cout << el << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The error message by g++ 5.4.0 reveals that `begin` is used instead of `cbegin`. Why?

```
temp.cpp: In function ‘void f(const A&)’:
temp.cpp:68:26: error: passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     for (const auto &el: a)
                          ^
temp.cpp:59:17: note:   in call to ‘A::KeyIterator A::begin()’
     KeyIterator begin() { return m.begin(); }
                 ^
temp.cpp:68:26: error: passing ‘const A’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     for (const auto &el: a)
                          ^
temp.cpp:61:17: note:   in call to ‘A::KeyIterator A::end()’
     KeyIterator end() { return m.end(); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range-based `for` *never* calls `cbegin`/`cend`. That's why you still need `const` versions of `begin`/`end` that return `const_iterator`s.